# TeamCity project for deployment fails with Exit Code 1

Tags: sql-server-2012, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I am adding a SQL script(StoredProc) for deployment using TeamCity Projects and the deployment fails and says(* Process exited with Code 1). It throws an **Error in Deploying script to DB**. But it was fine before.
Seems to me some issue with permissions, but I havent changed any.

Could anyone enlighten?

Comment: Please describe how you're attempting to add this script. What are the commands and parameters?

Comment: @JohnHoerr, thanks it has already worked. I was missing an error in build since yesterday.

Comment: Good! If you have time, you might consider posting your resolution here. It may help users with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this issue is resolved, I was missing a build error( was creating an SP in the script that I was deploying, but which already existed in DB with same name).
The exit code error message isnt always very descriptive, but stumbled upon "already exists" keyword somewhere in between the build-log. Hence rectified .
Good idea to examine log carefully.